# Get timezone of area with country code in Java

Tags: java, java-8, timezone, google-api-java-client, java-calendar

I have to pass a message (jms) with timezone info like (America/Los_Angeles) but I have only country name and code. If it possible get timezone info with Java code. Somewhere I read this:

```
System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US"));
```

But its giving output as

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
```

I am expecting List of "America/Los_Angeles", ...

Comment: _All_ timezones for a country?

Comment: yes a list if possible

Comment: It’s not built into Java. You may be able to find the information in some database somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the documentation the `getTimeZone` method returns the specified `TimeZone`, or the `GMT` zone if the given ID cannot be understood. There's no TimeZone ID called **US** hence it gives the GMT zone. If you really want to get all the list of TimeZones available in US, I would suggest you to use the following.

```
final List<String> timeZonesInUS = Stream.of(TimeZone.getAvailableIDs())
        .filter(zoneId -> zoneId.startsWith("US")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This will give you deprecated time zones like US/Alaska, not current ones like America/Adak or America/Los_Angeles. I’m not saying it’s not good enough, just think twice. It also won’t work for other country codes.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Can you suggest any other better way of doing this?

Comment: Sorry, not really, Ravindra Ranwala. One may of course try parsing [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) and use the country codes in the leftmost column of the table.

Comment: Have you tried this approach some other countries besides US? US is a simple example, but what about "AU" or some others that returns empty list? SO, is there any solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't.

Comment: Any solution for that? I would appreciated your suggestions.

Comment: I'll check it and let you know.

Answer (score 8):

The builtin Java classes don't offer this, but [ICU's TimeZone class](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/TimeZone.html#getAvailableIDs-java.lang.String-) does, and `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs("US")` provides the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly, it looks like you just want a list of timezones from a given country. This site has a list of all the countries that have their own code:

https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/what-are-the-java-timezone-ids/

Looking at the API for TimeZones shows that there's no way to grab a list of timezones directly through `TimeZone.getTimeZone()`. So instead, you probably want to loop through them and just see which ones start with the country name and add them to a list, like so:

```
public static List<String> GetZones(String country) {
    List<String> zones = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String i : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()) {
        if (i.startsWith(country)) {
            zones.add(i);
        }
    }
    return zones;

}
```

Comment: Timezones do not contain country name. They contain continent and city name