# Convert country-state code to time zone in Java

Tags: java, timezone

Having country-state code as input, is it possible to get the timezone using Java?
For example `us-tx -> (GMT-6)`

Tried using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50498146/get-timezone-of-area-with-country-code-in-java), however this method uses only the country code, without the state and the output is :

```
US/Alaska_US/Aleutian_US/Arizona_US/Central_US/East-Indiana_US/Eastern_US/Hawaii_US/Indiana-Starke_US/Michigan_US/Mountain_US/Pacific_US/Pacific-New_US/Samoa
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible - in any language.  Many US states have more than one time zone, depending on which part of the state you are referring to:

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_the_United_States):

[image: Time Zones of the United States]

You can clearly see on this map, many states where the time zone boundary does not follow the state boundary.